# Historical pronunciation of Hindi यह and वह

Tags: orthography, pronunciation, sound-change, allophones, hindustani

The Hindi 3rd person singular proximal and distal pronouns यह and वह are commonly pronounced [jeː] and [ʋoː], in contrast to the [hyper-correct?] pronunciations [jəɦ(ə)] and [ʋəɦ(ə)] one might expect from their spellings.

**Why are these words spelled this way given their pronunciation?** Apart from word-internal [schwa syncope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa_deletion_in_Indo-Aryan_languages#Hindi), Modern Standard Hindi pronunciation is generally predictable from spelling, so this seems an odd departure.

---

<sup>I tried to research this but found little credible information. Some possible reasons that jump to mind:</sup>

<sup>**1.** They used to be pronounced as spelled, but have since evolved (possibly influenced by the plural forms).</sup> 
<sup>**2.** A specific dialect pronounces them this way (that influenced the standard spelling).</sup> 
<sup>**3.** A phenomenon similar to how [ɛ] occurs as an allophone of /ə/ in /əɦə/ environments (e.g. बहन /bəɦən/ > [bɛɦ(ɛ)n]), or how [ɔ] occurs as an allophone of /ə/ and rounded vowels in /əɦ<sub>V[+round]</sub>/ or /<sub>V[+round]</sub>ɦə/ environments<sup>*</sup> (e.g. बहुत /bəhʊt̪/ > [bɔhɔt̪])?</sup>

<sup>***** i.e. /əɦʊ, əɦuː, əɦoː, əɦɔː/</sup>
   <sup>/ʊɦə, uːɦə, oːɦə, ɔːɦə/</sup>

Comment: Could you remind us of how they are spelt in Urdu?

Comment: @fdb يہ‎ and وہ‎ respectively.

Comment: Thanks. These imply in any event a short vowel.

Comment: 'वह' and 'यह' are often **pronounced** as 'वो' and 'ये' as speaking the extra 'ह' at the end takes a little more effort and time. 'वो' and 'ये' end in 'ो' and 'े', both 'svars' (स्वर)/vowels which can be spoken quickly.